# How to use HashMap when Json file has same key value

Tags: java, list, hashmap

My json file looks like this [actually it has more, I am just putting 2 blocks for example]

```
[{
        "answerValue": "2021-02-01",
        "parentId": "Policy",
        "instance": 1,
        "fieldId": "PolicyEffectiveDate"
    },
    {
        "answerValue": "2012",
        "parentId": "Insured",
        "instance": 1,
        "fieldId": "DateBusinessStarted"
    }
]
```

I want to store them in a HashMap and print them.

```
public void MapCheck() {

        Map<String, Object> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
        List<Map> lstMap = new ArrayList<>();


        dataMap.put("answerValue:", "2021-02-01");
        dataMap.put("parentId:", "Policy");
        dataMap.put("instance:", 1);
        dataMap.put("fieldId:", "PolicyEffectiveDate");
        lstMap.add(dataMap);

        dataMap.put("answerValue:", "Assurestart LLC");
        dataMap.put("parentId:", "Insured");
        dataMap.put("instance:", 1);
        dataMap.put("fieldId:", "Business_Name");
        lstMap.add(dataMap);

        System.out.println(lstMap);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();

        t.MapCheck();
    }
}
```

Expected: I wanted it to print

```
[{parentId:=Policy, fieldId:=PolicyEffectiveDate, answerValue:=2021-02-01, instance:=1}, {parentId:=Insured, fieldId:=Business_Name, answerValue:=Assurestart LLC, instance:=1}]
```

Actual: It is printing, the last value twice.

```
[{parentId:=Insured, fieldId:=Business_Name, answerValue:=Assurestart LLC, instance:=1}, {parentId:=Insured, fieldId:=Business_Name, answerValue:=Assurestart LLC, instance:=1}]
```

How can I make it print 2 different values? Thanks in advance for your time and ideas.

Comment: You're putting two references to the same hash map in your list. Just add `dataMap = new HashMap<>();` after the first call to `add`, so that you create a *new* map for the second element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a new map for the second map in the list:

```
    Map<String, Object> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
    List<Map<String, Object>> lstMap = new ArrayList<>();


    dataMap.put("answerValue:", "2021-02-01");
    dataMap.put("parentId:", "Policy");
    dataMap.put("instance:", 1);
    dataMap.put("fieldId:", "PolicyEffectiveDate");
    lstMap.add(dataMap);

    dataMap = new HashMap<>(); // create a new map!
    dataMap.put("answerValue:", "Assurestart LLC");
    dataMap.put("parentId:", "Insured");
    dataMap.put("instance:", 1);
    dataMap.put("fieldId:", "Business_Name");
    lstMap.add(dataMap);
```

That said, if you actually want to generate JSON, or read a JSON file, I recommend using a JSON serialisation/deserialisation library, such as [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson). That way, you can represent your data not as hash maps, but a class like this:

```
class MyObject {
    private String answerValue;
    private String parentId;
    private int instance;
    private String fieldId;

    // getters & setters...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You should create a new map for the second entry instead of overwriting the first entry’s values. Add

```
dataMap = new HashMap<>();
```

After adding the first entry to the list.

Answer (score 1):

HashMap as you know is a data structure that works based on unique key and value pair property.
In the example above when you perform dataMap.put("answerValue:", "2021-02-01"); it saves the value for this key in the HashMap. However when you perform, dataMap.put("answerValue:", "Assurestart LLC"); the second time, it will override the value of "answerValue:" key as it already exists there.

A better approach is to create a new class that can contain all this data in it and then you can decide on a unique key to store this data in. Thus your values will be an object that contains this entire block of data.
For example,

```
public class MyData {
private String answerValue;
private String parentId;
private Integer instance;
private String fieldId;

//Setters and getters
...

}
```